# Scheduled Synology Task with PHP

Tags: php, synology

Either synology won't let me do this, or my php script is bad

I've created my user defined script, so I used this as the script to call "php /volume7/homes/admin/scripts/ach_clean.php"

[image]

```
    <?php
  $files = glob(cacheme_directory()."/volume6/corp/AcctsPayable/*");
  $now   = time();

  foreach ($files as $file)
    if (is_file($file))
      if ($now - filemtime($file) >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) // 7 days
        fopen($file + ".test", "w");
        //unlink($file);
?>
```

Comment: Just while I test this script, to verify it found the correct file, I want it to create a file with part of the name. My Mentor taught me to be always very careful with scripts that delete files

Comment: I removed cacheme_directory()  since it gave a undefined function error. Now i am left with PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /volume7/homes/admin/scripts/ach_clean.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

forget PHP. It doesnt work as needed.

I just use shell instead. Simple, one liner.

find /volume6/corp/AcctsPayable/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +7 -delete